# Multiple jetty instances for different applications

Tags: java, deployment, jetty, web-deployment, jetty-9

I am new to applications deployments in web servers altogether. Is it OK to add different instances of jetty webserver for two application - One data service and another angular UI application. Or Do I need to deploy the two applications from the same jetty instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestions

#### Single jetty server hosting both applications

1. Use this approach when you own both the services and understand the RPS/throughout/latency/memory requirements of both the services. A bottleneck in one service can cause issue to another service
2. If the available memory/cpu/capacity is limited and hence don't want to waste additional memory for server by running another server instance
3. Both services are light weight
4. Both services are not deployed frequently or there is proper a BCP

#### Separate jetty server per application - preferably containerized(Docker?)

1. Provides good isolation to services
2. Control over resources per application
3. Easy to manage/scale independently depending on load
4. Easy to identify and fix issues

Personally, i would prefer to run them independently with or without containerization.

Comment: Running them independently will also have an advantage that angular needs index.html to be loaded before it can resolve a resource. So if you happen to curl directly then you get a 404 but if index.html was loaded then it will send back the appropriate response. There would be a conflict on which service should resolve a given address which can be avoided by separating them.

Comment: This means , we need to download two  separate jetty webserver zip folders and follow these steps, right - https://www.baeldung.com/deploy-to-jetty

Comment: @Abhi Yes, that is the overhead of isolation/containerization. In the long run, it will always be easy to manage and debug applications in isolated environments. Also, from security perspective, it will be better manage instances independently.